# Azure AD User Provisioning with SCIM 2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim, scim2

I'm trying SCIM 2.0 provisioning with Azure AD

As premise, I have SCIM a server for my product and I'm implementing PATCH endpoints for use with Okta and Microsoft Azure AD.

I'm done testing with Okta, so I'm trying with Azure AD now.

I read this post [active-directory-scim-provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-scim-provisioning) and the SCIM 2.0 Specification [Section 3.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.5.2).

I set up an enterprise application on our Azure AD with the following mapping
[image: mapping]

Then, Azure AD sends the following JSON POST request to create users assigned to the application to my server:

**POST:**

```
{
  "active": true,
  "displayName": "$DISPLAY_NAME", 
  "emails": [
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            "primary": true,
            "type": "work",
            "value": "$EMAIL"
        }
    ],
    "externalId": "$EXTERNAL_ID",
    "meta": {
        "resourceType": "User"
    },
    "name": {
        "formatted": "$FORMATTED"
    },
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
    ],
    "userName": "$USER_NAME"
}
```

I can process the POST request correctly, but I am unable to consume the PATCH request from Azure AD.

**PATCH:**

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    "Operations": [
        {   
            "op": "Replace",
            "path": "name.givenName",
            "value": [
                {   
                    "$ref": null,
                    "value": "$VALUE"
                }   
            ]
        },  
        {   
            "op": "Replace",
            "path": "name.familyName",
            "value": [
                {   
                    "$ref": null,
                    "value": "$VALUE"
                }   
            ]   
        }   
    ],  
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ]   
}
```

Is it correct (according to the specification) that the `value` attribute is of type Array, even if the target is a single-valued attribute? Is the use of the `$ref` attribute correct in this case?

Or did I misunderstand the specification?

Comment: I wondered the same thing. Did you find an answer from MS?  Also, they send booleans as strings, e.g. "True" instead of true.

Comment: @thesmart Unfortunately No I didn't, I just implemented special logic for support strange format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They made a mistake on the `value` implementation for non-complex objects. You can read more about it here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e2200b69-4333-41ea-9f51-717d316c7751/automatic-user-provisioning-scim-restful-patch-payload-issue?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 2):

They have fixed it Dec 18 2018 :)

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-provisioning-config-problem-scim-compatibility